# SQL*loader infile replace function

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to change SQL*loader files to replace a comma in decimal numbers with a dot.

**How the loader data file looks**

```
Pamatstudijas,Lauksaimniecibas,4,16.01.2006,70,"5,38"
```

**My control file**

```
load data
 infile 'C:\Users\Students\Documents\ricardshercbergs_itia\12\izmaksas1.dat'
 into table kartoteka
 fields terminated by "," Optionally Enclosed By '"'
 TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (stud_veids char, 
fakultate char, 
kurss Integer External, 
izmaksas_datums date 'dd.mm.yyyy',
stipendija Integer External,
kompensacija  "REPLACE (:kompensacija,',','.')" Decimal External ,
nauda_kopa ":stipendija+:kompensacija")
```

This: `kompensacija  "REPLACE (:kompensacija,',','.')" Decimal External ,` doesnt work as I expected. I get the error:

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 11.
Expecting "," or ")", found keyword decimal.
kompensacija  "REPLACE (:kompensacija,',','.')" Decimal External ,
```

Comment: sql loader is oracle I think. Is question tagged correctly?

Comment: Yes, i wil change tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [example control file in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-413DEE17-FA16-4AD7-A5E6-0A6D8BFE0057) the definition of the datatype comes before the transformation of the column, i.e. your spec should be:

```
kompensacija  Decimal External "REPLACE (:kompensacija,',','.')"
```

It looks possible you're using `REPLACE()` to switch around what character is a decimal point and which is the thousands separator. If this is the case you can use [`TO_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions227.htm#SQLRF06140), which makes it more obvious what you're doing and will fail with the correct error if the conversion is not possible:

```
kompensacija decimal external "to_number(:kompensacija, '99D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')"
```